# How to prevent jumping to top of screen during jQuery animations

Tags: jquery

I have multiple  links that show/hide divs throughout (using `slideDown()`).  Each of the links are

```
<a href="#">Link</a>
```

Everytime you click on the link, it jumps back to the top of the screen while it animates.  I'm assuming it's because of the `#`.  Is there any way in jQuery to focus on the animation rather than jump to the top of the screen each time?  Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the onClick handler, disable the default action of the anchor element ...

`$('a').click(function(e) {


e.preventDefault();


// ANIMATION STUFF GOES HERE...


});`

Answer (score 2):

You will need to return `false` in the function you have bound to the link's click event.

Comment: That is wrong, he will not have to. He can do so. But if he wants the event to bubble on, he should only call `preventDefault` and not return false from the function.

Comment: So if what I suggested works, and the question didn't mention event bubbling, how is it wrong?

Comment: @Axsuul event handlers can cascade... e.g. when you have DOM objects inside each others. If you return false from event handler, the event is considered consumed and the other guys don't get to see it, otherwise it propagates to the parent objects

Answer (score 0):

Use `return false` at the end of the click function.

```
$(function(){
    $("#an1").click(function(){
         // your animation code
         return false;
    });
});

<a id="an1" href="#">click me</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

In the event handler function, use `e.preventDefault();`, assuming `e` is the event object. Optionally, return false from the handler function.